# Call code outside of IIFE from within IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

I have code that successfully calls a function in an IIFE that, in turn, references code outside of the IIFE that I can't figure out how to call.

```
const msgbox = (function () {
  function showMsgBox(msg) {
    const modal = document.createElement("div");
    modal.classList.add("modal");
    modal.innerHTML = `<div class="modal-content"><p>${msg}</p></div>`;
    document.body.appendChild(modal);
    modal.style.display = "block";
    window.onclick = function (event) {
      if (event.target === modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    };
  }
  return {
    showMsgBox: showMsgBox
  };
})();

  const example = document.getElementById("example");

  function changeClass() {
    if (example.getAttribute("class") === "classTwo") {
      example.classList.remove("classTwo");
      example.classList.add("classOne");
    } else {
      example.classList.add("classTwo");
      example.classList.remove("classOne");
    }
  }

  document.querySelectorAll(".change_class").forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      changeClass();
    });
  });
  
  document.querySelector(".showmsg").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    msgbox.showMsgBox(
      'Call Function outside of IIFE=> <button class="change_class">Change Class</button> (<= this button should have the same functionality as the other button)'
    );
  });
```

I tried putting the non-IIFE section into its own IIFE and giving it a separate namespace but that didn't work. The example above is a simplified version of my actual problem, but this encapsulates my problem more succinctly and makes it less confusing. Yes, I could make the IIFE simply a function and call it that way, but I'm trying to expand my knowledge.

Here's a link to the CodePen example I created for this:
https://codepen.io/NoahBoddy/pen/PoOVMzK
Hopefully, my explanation is clear. If not, I can provide more detail. Thanks!

Comment: misunderstood ... so are you saying `msgbox.showMsgBox(....)` is failing in some undisclosed way? is it because after calling `.showMsgBox` the `item.addEventListener("click"` above isn't automagically added to the new element? it won't be - that code has run already

Comment: @Bravo No. The problem I'm having is getting the "change Class" button to work from within the modal. Check out the CodePen example.

Comment: exactly, because the event listener isn't added, because you don't add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the new button doesn't run the click event code is because it isn't added to it

Once

```
document.querySelectorAll(".change_class").forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    changeClass();
  });
});
```

runs, that's it. Any NEW elements with that class don't make the above code run again automagically

You could add the same event handler to the newly created button it once you've created the button - that's tedious, and duplicates code - if you need to make a change, you may need to change multiple places. A recipe for bad code.

or ... here's a solution using event delegation

```js
const msgbox = (function () {
    function showMsgBox(msg) {
        const modal = document.createElement("div");
        modal.classList.add("modal");
        modal.innerHTML = `<div class="modal-content"><p>${msg}</p></div>`;
        document.body.appendChild(modal);
        modal.style.display = "block";
        window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (event.target === modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        };
    }
    return {
        showMsgBox: showMsgBox
    };
})();

const example = document.getElementById("example");
function changeClass() {
    if (example.getAttribute("class") === "classTwo") {
        example.classList.remove("classTwo");
        example.classList.add("classOne");
    } else {
        example.classList.add("classTwo");
        example.classList.remove("classOne");
    }
}
const change_class = document.getElementsByClassName("change_class");
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if ([...change_class].includes(e.target)) {
        changeClass();
    }
});

document.querySelector(".showmsg").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    msgbox.showMsgBox('<button class="change_class">Change Class</button>');
});
```

```css
* { font-family: sans-serif; }
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.classOne {
  background: #088;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.classTwo {
  background: #808;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="change_class">Change Class</button>
<br><br>
<div id="example" class="classOne">This will alternately use 'classOne' and 'classTwo'</div>
<br>
<button class="showmsg">Show MsgBox</button>
```

As noted in the code `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `live` list (querySelectorAll does NOT)

This means that any new elements added with the specified class will appear in that list without you needing to do anything. Same for removed elements, they just disappear from the list

note: `getElementsByClassName` is also a method on any element, so you don't have to get all such elements in the document, you could use it to just get the target elements under a selected element in the DOM - not applicable to this code as is, but something that may be useful

Comment: The changeClass function doesn't seem to run. Am I missing something?

Comment: It does in this answer - perhaps you've done it wrong in your code - I can't see what you wrote, but, if you look at the code in this answer you can see that it is the code in your question with changes applied to make it work

Comment: I just made the change on your codepen, and it works - so, you did it wrong - you probably forgot to remove the `document.querySelectorAll(".change_class")` code if I were to guess

Comment: Can you post the link to the one that works? If I screwed it up, I can handle that! Just want to see it work... thanks!

Comment: nope, I don't have a codepen account

Comment: I've copied your codepen code exactly to the snippet, with my fix to prove that it works.

Comment: I made the changes here https://codepen.io/NoahBoddy/pen/WNXmeEe but I'm obviously not getting it...

Comment: Your codepen works fine

Comment: fixed ... should be using `e.target` not `e.originalTarget` - my bad, not sure why I even used that property  since it's non-standard firefox only - so damned Firefox, not damned Chrome :p

Comment: Yeah, the original answer not working was my fault :p thanks for your patience @Realto619

Comment: Ha! I was actually thinking thanks for YOUR patience!

Answer (score 1):

The button in the modal has no `click` handler, so it does nothing:

```js
msgbox.showMsgBox(
   'Call Function outside of IIFE=> <button class="change_class">Change Class</button> (<= this button should have the same functionality as the other button)'
);
```

You could either set the `click` handler inline:

```js
msgbox.showMsgBox(                             
   'Call Function outside of IIFE=> <button onclick="changeClass()" class="change_class">Change Class</button> (<= this button should have the same functionality as the other button)'
);
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ZEaPzpQ)

OR you could update `showMsgBox()` to add the handler:

```js
function showMsgBox(msg) {
  const modal = document.createElement("div");
  ⋮
  modal.querySelectorAll(".change_class").forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      changeClass();
    });
  });
}
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/eYeXOBZ)

Comment: I already have it set up   
document.querySelectorAll(".change_class").forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      changeClass();
    });
  });
but that doesn't trigger it. Is it not possible to have it work that way?

Comment: Because you ran that BEFORE adding the new button with that class - it doesn't get run automagically when you add a new button